# Any way to get MVC Authorization statistics of an application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller

I'm now building an application in MVC5. Data of different corporations are stored in the same database and people access them under the control of "[Authorize(...)]" and some other costumed filters. With the growing of controllers and actions, I'm more and more worried about the security, for example: is there any actions without authorization or with wrong authorization?

So the question is: Is there any 
1. Report views in Visual Studio (might not designed to do the work)
2. Third part tools
3. Something else

that give a clear map of authorization of all controllers/actions? This is a critical work and I think there should be some solutions rather than check through all those code files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [FluentSecurity](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/getting-started) because of this. From their docs:

> Ignoring missing configurations
>
> By default FluentSecurity will throw an exception if a missing
>   configuration is encountered for a controller action. If you don't
>   want FluentSecurity to handle security for all controllers you can
>   tell it to ignore missing configurations. You can do this by adding
>   configuration.IgnoreMissingConfiguration(); to your configuration
>   expression.

It puts security configurations in a single file, makes them unit testable, and is generally useful. There is a small learning curve to figuring out how to bootstrap it and get it set up. You can install it and get going quickly using nuget.

Besides this, there arent really any tools that I know of that can do the reporting that you are asking about... unless you want to write a battery of unit tests against each actionmethod:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountControllerTests {

    [Test]
    public void Verify_ChangePassword_Method_Is_Decorated_With_Authorize_Attribute() {
        var controller = new AccountController();
        var type = controller.GetType();
        var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ChangePassword", new Type[] { typeof(ChangePasswordModel) });
        var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true);
        Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any(), "No AuthorizeAttribute found on ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model) method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late and thanks for the answer. But in fact, it's the answer of my 2nd step: how to test them. And the first answer is: "How many actions have I get and are they all authorized?" Now what I'm worrying is that there might be some actions without authorization, and as new actions are added every day, it's hard to track them :(